# capture keyboard inputs on a web page in javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to control input focus of a web page using javascript. Actually, I'm developing a webExtension that loads content-script on a webpage. The web page is pre-designed to auto-collect keyboard inputs. However, I want my script to receive keyboard inputs on certain occasions  through an inputBox I attached to the page. But all keyboard inputs seems to go the original inputBox of the page. This is my current draft

```
//TODO: steal focus to myInputBox
//while keydown is shiftkey, steal and retain the focus on myInputBox
//subsequently collect keyboard inputs
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
 if (e.shiftKey)    
 {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent shiftkey from modifying the input, I guess. Still learning though
  document.getElementById("myInputBox").focus(); //focus myInputBox subsequently accepting keyboard input from now on...
 }
});
```

but the keyboard inputs still goes to the original inputBox

///////Good, I have found a fix. This is my fix, it may be of help to some other person

```
document.addEventListener("keyup",function(){

if (e.key == "A" || e.key == "a")
{
    var origInput = document.getElementById("origInputID");

    origInput.disabled = !origInput.disabled;//use "!" to toggle current 
                                            //state
    if (origInput.disabled === true)
    {
        document.getElementById("myInput").focus();
    }
}});
```

Comment: Do you want focus returned when shift is up?

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me.  I updated it so it types in the alternate box when shift is down, and then types in the original box when shift is up.  Not really sure if that's what you wanted...

To get unshifted characters while the shift key is down, you might have to track the shift key state, and switch on the **keycode** then.  I don't think you can't prevent the shift key from affecting the generated **charcode**.  Preventing default will not cause different charcodes from being generated, the keycode will be constant.

Character codes - A number which represents an ASCII character

Key codes - A number which represents an actual key on the keyboard

```js
let editMode = false

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey && !editMode) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    editMode = true
    document.getElementById("myInputBox").focus();
  }
})

document.getElementById("myInputBox").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (editMode && !e.shiftKey) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    editMode = false
    document.getElementById("other").focus();
  }
})

document.getElementById("other").focus();
```

```html
Start with focus here, then press and hold shift
<input id='other'></input>
<hr />
Target
<input id='myInputBox'></input>
```

Comment: Yah thanks, my code works just like you rightly pointed out but the shift key is modifying the keyboard inputs and when I turn on e.preventDefault, the code stops working. what i want is to make the shiftkey editMode activator ONLY not  modifier as it is defaulted i.e while holding the shiftKey, then press key "2" on the keyboard, i should get "2" not the character "@" contrast to shiftKey default behaviour